# Calculating total not returning anything React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, numbers, subtotal

I'm building a basic shop app using React. So here I have this function that calculates the final price of the products. Code:

```
    calculateTotal = () => {
    const total2 =
      this.state.final_apple_price +
      this.state.final_avocado_price +
      this.state.final_branzino_price +
      this.state.final_bread_price +
      this.state.final_burger_price +
      this.state.final_carrot_price +
      this.state.final_cheese_price +
      this.state.final_chicken_price +
      this.state.final_donut_price +
      this.state.final_egg_price +
      this.state.final_falooda_price +
      this.state.final_milk_price +
      this.state.final_muffin_price +
      this.state.final_orange_price +
      this.state.final_pizza_price +
      this.state.final_potato_price +
      this.state.final_salmon_price +
      this.state.final_strawberry_price;
    this.setState({ total: total2 });
  };
```

The state has:

```
total: 0,
```

And here it's supposed to return the values of all the products:

```
<h1>{this.state.total}</h1>
```

However, 0 is displayed in the h1, even when items are added.

Another thing which I tried in the calculateTotal function is -

```
return total2;
```

and

```
<h1>{this.calculateTotal()}</h1>
```

Still, it isn't working. How to fix?
Thanks

Comment: just return the value insted , use <h3>{calculateTotal()}</h3>

Comment: @AnoopJoshiP when I am doing that my screen goes blank.

Comment: this.calsulateTotal() might soleve the issue I think

Comment: @AnoopJoshiP actually I tried this.calculateTotal() because calculateTotal gives an error.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @AnoopJoshiP `Line 1492:24:  'calculateTotal' is not defined  no-undef`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what the first comment meant.

```
calculateTotal = () => {
    return this.state.final_apple_price +
      this.state.final_avocado_price +
      this.state.final_branzino_price +
      this.state.final_bread_price +
      this.state.final_burger_price +
      this.state.final_carrot_price +
      this.state.final_cheese_price +
      this.state.final_chicken_price +
      this.state.final_donut_price +
      this.state.final_egg_price +
      this.state.final_falooda_price +
      this.state.final_milk_price +
      this.state.final_muffin_price +
      this.state.final_orange_price +
      this.state.final_pizza_price +
      this.state.final_potato_price +
      this.state.final_salmon_price +
      this.state.final_strawberry_price;
  };

  // ...
  // inside render
  `<h3>{this.calculateTotal()}</h3>`
```

Comment: Yes, I did this, but my react website goes blank if I try that.

Comment: Would you be able to add more code from `render` and the updated `calculateTotal`?

Comment: What I actually mean is if you could edit the post and add more parts of your code, specifically the `render` method and the latest `calculateTotal`. I'm asking because I don't know what else could be wrong earlier other than that setState({total: ...}) might be triggering infinite rerender.

Comment: This part of your post should have fixed it:
```
Another thing which I tried in the calculateTotal function is -
return total2;
and
<h1>{this.calculateTotal()}</h1>
```

when you said this,
> @AnoopJoshiP Line 1492:24:  'calculateTotal' is not defined  no-undef 

were you calling `{this.calculateTotal()}` or `{calculateTotal()}`?
also, you are sure the `render` and `calculateTotal` is both inside a class component?

Comment: `calculateTotal()` because `this.calculateTotal()` wasn't working.

Comment: Yes, render and calculateTotal is both inside a class component. I guess this discussion is getting me nowwhere, lets leave this, I'll try to find a different solution. Thanks for your help

Comment: sorry we couldn't find a solution. Goodluck!